# Upload a file like a human being on Linux in Command Line

Tags: linux, command-line, file-upload, centos, swfupload

I am using VPS with CentOS 5.5. I need to upload some files to a website. From the source code, i know that this website using [SWFUpload](http://u.115.com/static/swfup/swfup_min.js) to upload files.

I want to upload some files to this website like a human being does, that includes click the button, select the file etc.

Any programming language is fine, Python, PHP, etc

Please give me some hints. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Live HTTP Header (plug in of firefox) to inspect what kind of packets were exchanged between your host and server. Then you can use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to generate these packets again (by command or by programming).

Answer (score 2):

Use a packet capture tool and do an upload by hand from your browser to see what HTTP traffic the flash applet generates, then you can duplicate the same request using a tool of your choice.